# Not enough storage is available to complete this operation - VB6

Tags: vb6

We are getting Error "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" for a VB6 windows application in Windows 2012 R2 Server. The same functionality is working in Windows 7 Machine and in Windows 2008 R2 server with the same build.

Is it related environment? How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have anything meaningful logged in the system's event logger?  Are you running it as admin?  If you run it from the IDE and break on the error, what is it trying to do?

Comment: Does it let you log in first? or do you get this error as you try to log in?

Comment: Is the VB6 application leaking memory?

Comment: @BobSki Log in works fine. But one save mechanism fails.

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips I don't think there is any memory leak. I used DebugDiag to check this.

Comment: @LukeG. Unfortunately there is nothing coming in the event log too for this application.

Comment: Can you install VB6 on this server and run the program in the IDE so you can break on the error?  If not, it is still possible to use and output the line numbers in an error message in VB6.  But if you can run the IDE there it would be better.

Comment: @LukeG. I dont think VB6 IDE is supported in 2012 R2 server

Comment: @AmitKumar According to the directions for Windows 8 here (https://visualproblem.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/how-to-install-vb6-on-windows-vista7-8/), which is roughly 2012 R2-ish enough, it should be installable and usable.  Please note the updates in the comments thread for some 2012 R2-specific tweaks to make the install work.